# Coefficients of the Weierstrass $\wp$'s Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

I am trying to study the Weierstrass $\wp$ function using a combination of texts from Alfors; Cartan; Freitag and Busam; and Siegel. But I am having some trouble because I would like to try to avoid starting from the Ansatz equation approach given in most of the texts.

I would like to derive the coefficients of $\wp$'s Laurent expansion by considering the differential equation

$$(\wp^{\prime})^{2}=4\wp^{3} -g_{2}\wp(w) - g_{3}.\qquad (1)$$

By writing 
$$\wp = \sum_{k=-N}^{\infty}a_{k}\omega^{k}\qquad (2)$$

and substituting (2) into (1) to get the form

$$\wp(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega^{2}} + a_{2}\omega^{2} + a_{4}\omega^{4} + \dots\qquad (3)$$

where I found $(3)$ in Freitag and Busam's *Complex Analysis*. Intuition I gained from studying the Ansatz equation approach suggests this must be true, but even considering this for small $N$, the combination of the derivative (I am assuming I can safely differentiate term wise) and the cubic are creating multinomial expansions that seem to have no hope of cancellation when powers of $\omega$ are compared on the left and the right hand side.

Using achille hue's suggestion and some additional work, I was able to reduce the problem down to

$$\wp(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega^{2}} + a_{1}w^{2} + a_{2}w^{4} + \dots$$

Further substitution into the differential equation

$$\wp^{\prime\prime}(\omega) = 6(\wp(\omega))^{2} - \frac{g_{2}}{2}$$
yields

$$\frac{6}{\omega^{4}} +2b_{1} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(2k)(2k-1)b_{k}\omega^{2k} = 6\left[ \frac{1}{\omega^{2}}  + b_{1}\omega^{2} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}b_{k}\omega^{2k}\right]^{2} - \frac{g_{2}}{2}.$$

and the article here from [mathworld.wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html) mentions the existence of a recurrence relation closed form solution given by equation (7). I figured I may be able to find all the coefficients in one swoop from achille's hint, but I cannot sniff out the next step to reproduce the relation.

Comment: You should consider $\wp''(z) = 6 \wp(z)^2 - \frac{g_2}{2}$ instead. it will be much simpler.

Comment: On the LHS, the sum should be $\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2k(2k-1)b_k \omega^{2k\color{red}{-2}}$. On the RHS, partially expand the square and handle terms depend on $\frac{1}{\omega^2}$ separately. $b_1$ will be fixed by $g_2$ and every else (aside form $b_2$) can be expressed recursively in terms of $b_1$ and $b_2$. At the end, you use $(1)$ to fix the last coefficient $b_2$.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you for your help. If you would like me to accept your previous comment as an answer I would be happy to.